# Alternative way to use a dictionary in a domain object

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

My domain object has a list of objects that gets updated constantly. I have this collection as a list for now. But for every update I'd have to constantly do a .Where().FirstOrDefault(). It is much better to use a Dictionary for my purpose which would make accessing the object I want much faster, but I can't use the Dictionary because then mapping the dictionary in my Entity configuration is not supported at all.

```
using System.Collections.Immutable;

namespace SessionTracker.Domain
{
 public class Session
 {
    private readonly Dictionary<int, SessionScore> _sessionScores = new();
    private readonly List<SessionScore> _lsessionScores = new();

    protected Session() { }

    public Session(int playerId, Dictionary<int, long> startScores, DateTime timestamp)
    {
        PlayerId = playerId;
        StartDateTime = timestamp;
        foreach (var item in startScores)
        {
            if (!_sessionScores.ContainsKey(item.Key))
            {
                _sessionScores.Add(item.Key, new SessionScore(item.Key, item.Value, timestamp));
            }
        }
    }

    public void Update(Dictionary<int, long> startScores, DateTime timestamp)
    {
        foreach (var item in startScores)
        {
            if (!_sessionScores.ContainsKey(item.Key))
            {
                _sessionScores.Add(item.Key, new SessionScore(item.Key, item.Value, timestamp));
            }
            else
            {
                _sessionScores[item.Key].Update(item.Value, timestamp);
            }
        }
    }

    public void End(Dictionary<int, long> startScores, DateTime timestamp)
    {
        foreach (var item in startScores)
        {
            if (!_sessionScores.ContainsKey(item.Key))
            {
                _sessionScores.Add(item.Key, new SessionScore(item.Key, item.Value, timestamp));
            }
            else
            {
                _sessionScores[item.Key].Update(item.Value, timestamp);
            }
        }
        EndDateTime = timestamp;
    }

    public int PlayerId { get; }
    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; }
    public DateTime? EndDateTime { get; private set; }
    public ImmutableDictionary<int, SessionScore> SessionScores => _sessionScores.ToImmutableDictionary();

    public List<SessionScore> LSessionScores => _lsessionScores.ToList();
}
```

}

My EF Core configuration class in my infrastructure layer,

```
public class SessionConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Session>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Session> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(ps => ps.Id);

        builder.Property(ps => ps.PlayerId).IsRequired();

        //This is acceptable since LSessionScores is a list
        builder.HasMany(ps => ps.LSessionScores)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(sm => sm.SessionId)
            .IsRequired();

        //This is not acceptable since SessionScores is a dictionary
        builder.HasMany(ps => ps.SessionScores)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(sm => sm.SessionId)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Is there any alternative way to design my domain to make it compatible with EF Core?

Comment: Where does EF comes into play? What model mapping you are talking about? A specific mapping product?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a compound collection implementing `ICollection<T>`  and also integrating a dictionary. EF Core would be happy with it as you can declare Navigation properties as `ICollection<T>`. Something like this:

```cs
public class KeyedCollection<TKey, TValue>(Func<TValue, TKey> getKey) : ICollection<TValue>
    where TKey : notnull
{
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, TValue> _dictionary = [];
    private readonly List<TValue> _list = [];

    public int Count => _list.Count;

    public bool IsReadOnly => false;

    public void Add(TValue value)
    {
        _list.Add(value);
        _dictionary.Add(getKey(value), value);
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        _list.Add(value);
        _dictionary.Add(key, value);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, [NotNullWhen(true)] out TValue? value) 
        => _dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value!);

    public void Clear()
    {
        _list.Clear();
        _dictionary.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(TValue item) => _dictionary.ContainsKey(getKey(item));

    public void CopyTo(TValue[] array, int arrayIndex) => _list.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);

    public IEnumerator<TValue> GetEnumerator() => _list.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => _list.GetEnumerator();
    public bool Remove(TValue item)
    {
        _list.Remove(item);
        return _dictionary.Remove(getKey(item));
    }

}
```

Note that I used C# 12.0 features.
The primary constructor accepts a `Func<TValue, TKey> getKey` delegate, so that you can add items through `ICollection<TValue>.Add(TValue value)` and still get the required key for the dictionary.